# Wordpress bootstrap css3 styling error in IE

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap on wordpress and so far the only issue is that the styling is appearing weird on IE 7,8 and 9.
I'm assuming its because IE is in quirks mode.

Can I get all styling right for IE? So far i've tried `respond.js` and `cssmediaqueries.js`. Also the carousel works fine on the other browsers except for IE.

Website: www.kbbcredit.com

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, just putting a tag on the top of your html such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

works!

It means, you want to use html5.